# Must type multiple times, before scanner reads input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

If I run this code

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner();
while (true) {
        if (sc.next().equals("1"))
            System.out.println("--1--");

        else if (sc.next().equals("2"))
            System.out.println("--2--");

        else if (sc.next().equals("3"))
            System.out.println("--3--");

        else if (sc.next().equals("4"))
            System.out.println("--4--");

        else if (sc.next().equals("help"))
            System.out.println("--help--");
    }
```

It will not read the first time I type enter. I have to type 2-4 times before it reads the input. A session could look like this:

```
1
1
1
1
--1--
3
3
--3--
help
2
1
help
--help--
```

No matter what I type, it will only read the last input of the four inputs.
Sometimes it reads after two inputs. I'm really confused about this.
Should I instead use multiple scanners?

Answer (score 3):

Your concepts are wrong here.

Each time you ask for `sc.next()` it will wait for the input. If that input is equal to what you want it to be, then the code is executed.

You can correct this by storing `sc.next()` in a String variable, and then comparing it.

Here:
`if (sc.next().equals("1"))`
it asks for an input.

If that input is `1` then the code is executed and `--1--` is printed out. Else, it jumps to this: `if (sc.next().equals("2"))`. Now if the input is `2` then the code to print `--2--` is executed. Else, it jumps to `if (sc.next().equals("3"))` and so on.

You can correct this by:

- storing `sc.next()` in a String variable, and then comparing it.
- using a switch-case block to compare the input.

Comment: LMAO, I thought it was something like this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `sc.next()` multiple times - so if the input isn't 1, it's going to wait for more input to see whether the *next* input is 2, etc. Each call to `sc.next()` will wait for *more* input. It doesn't have any idea of "that isn't the input you were looking for, so I'll return the same value next time you call".

Use a local variable to store the result of `sc.next()`

```
while (true) {
    String next = sc.next();
    if (next.equals("1"))
        System.out.println("--1--");
    else if (next.equals("2"))
        System.out.println("--2--");
    else if (next.equals("3"))
        System.out.println("--3--");
    else if (next.equals("4"))
        System.out.println("--4--");
    else if (next.equals("help"))
        System.out.println("--help--");
}
```

Also consider using a switch statement instead...

Comment: This fixed it, and yes, I will use switch instead. Thanks!

Comment: @yeahboy when do you type help? Show us your new code. I guess you are having a problem similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods]

Answer (score 0):

You are calling sc.next() multiple times

Solution code :

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            switch (scanner.next()) {
                case "1":
                    System.out.println("--1--");
                    break;
                case "2":
                    System.out.println("--2--");
                    break;
                case "3":
                    System.out.println("--3--");
                    break;
                case "4":
                    System.out.println("--4--");
                    break;
                case "help":
                    System.out.println("--help--");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```